# Why does the derivative of $f(x)=\frac{8}{x^{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{x}n(x-n)$ approach 4/3?

Tags: derivatives, summation

Does anyone know why the derivative of the function $$f(x)=\frac{8}{x^2}\sum_{n=0}^{x}n(x-n)$$ approaches $\frac43$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$?

For context, the function
$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{8}{x^{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{x}\sqrt{n\left(x-n\right)}$$ approaches $\pi$.

Comment: How do you define the sum for non-integer values of $x$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: HINT. Just compute the sum to find $f(x)$ and derive.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca In this case, it doesn't actually matter which integer we are relating $x$ to, provided it is near $x$. Whether we take $\lfloor x \rfloor$ or $\lceil x \rceil$ or even $\lfloor x \rfloor + 3$, we have the same slope of the asymptote. But regardless, the question should have been asked with full details.